# How to convert excel or csv file to html table in django?

Tags: python, django, excel, csv

I have a small application where user can submit an excel or csv file and I want to display the data in that file to the user on the template. How can I do this?

I know about libraries like openpyxl and xlrd, they're both python libraries and can loop through the file and display the values, but then getting those values over to the template seems like too much work (If that's the only way to do it, I'm going to do it).

Is there another way? This is what I have so far:

```
def home(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        uploaded_file = request.FILES['my_excel']
        # What should I do here?

    return (render(request, 'demo/index.html'))
```

Comment: A simple way to do this if you don't mind the overhead is to use the [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/) module. You can read in the `csv/excel` directly into a `DataFrame` which has the the function [`DataFrame.to_html()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_html.html)

Answer (score 0):

I use JSON encoded data and https://handsontable.com to render it.

- the JSON data needs to be escaped, but for my use case it is generally more compact the HTML: the libraries you mention can do the reading.
- the handsontable documentation is very good and it is easy to get started https://docs.handsontable.com/pro/3.0.0/tutorial-quick-start.html:

> ```
> // Django part.
> let food = {{ data|escapejs }};
> // Handsontable example
> let data = [
>     ["", "Ford", "Tesla", "Toyota", "Honda"],
>     ["2017", 10, 11, 12, 13],
>     ["2018", 20, 11, 14, 13],
>     ["2019", 30, 15, 12, 13]
> ];
> let container = document.getElementById('example');
> let hot = new Handsontable(container, {
>     data: data,
>     rowHeaders: true,
>     colHeaders: true,
>     filters: true,
>     dropdownMenu: true
> });
> ```

The resulting table can use the extensive spreadsheet-like facilities that hot provides, and is easy to interface to Ajax if needed.